# Binding a keypress to a frame in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I looked everywhere for an answer, so I come here. The question is simple: why binding key pressing (e.g. Escape) doesn't work on frames? Example:

```
pack [frame .f]
bind .f <Escape> exit; #won't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames can process key events just fine, but don't usually as they usually don't have the focus and won't take it by default when you click on them or use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle around the things that are focusable.

The most direct fix is to just do:

```
focus .f
```

That makes keyboard events go to the frame *now*. However, you probably want to use this so that you can click-to-focus:

```
bind .f <1> {focus %W}
```

And this so that the widget participates in the tab-traversal:

```
.f configure -takefocus 1
```

Lastly, frames don't *show* anything when they have the focus since the configure their “highlight thickness” to have zero width. Let's change that:

```
.f configure -highlightthickness 2
```

That should be all you need (or at least it works for me when I test).

Comment: Thank you very much! That's all I need.